Access to Azure Keyvault inside Azure Container Instance WebApi
I would like to retrive the keyvault secrets using managed identity in web Api.

Creates Web APi with DefaultAzureCredential



Able to retrive the data using aboe code.
Built image and pushed into Azure container registry
Created azure container instace using above image
Provided Key Vault Reader and Key Vault Secrets User by slected the instance using managed identity
When I try to access the API that reads the data from AzureKeyVault, it is giving 404 erro.

ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: DefaultIdentityNotDefined \r\nStatus: 404 (Not Found)\r\nErrorCode: DefaultIdentityNotDefined\r\n\r\nContent:\r\n{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "DefaultIdentityNotDefined
How can I access the keyvault data inside container instace web api?

Did you assign the permissions to the managed identity of the container app or the container app environment?

Yes. I have assigned the roles but still it is not giving response

Are you using Kubernetes containers? or are you using Container-Apps (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/container-apps/)?

Did you solve your issue with MrPatience and JuanMedina answers?

It seems you're using Azure Container Apps and you have 2 options in there:

Use of System Managed Identity (recommended)
Use of User Managed Identity

For any of them, the configuration must be enabled and done like this:

And the process to do so it's defined in the oficial documentation in here
Also, in order to have access to the KeyVault Secrets, you must add an Access Policy to that Managed Identity with at least Get and List secrets. It might be worth to take a look at the section to add the KV Secret references to your Container App in here
As per the error, it seems you haven't enable the Managed Identity yet; therefore, there would be no Identity defined to connect to the KV.
UPDATE
Since what you're using is Azure Container Instance, then you should follow the official guide for enabling the Managed Identity

It is not a container app. It is a container instance. I dont see an option on container instace

I just updated the answer with the link to the information you need

If you look into the docs of DefaultAzureCredential, it combines several credential types:

EnvironmentCredential
...
ManagedIdentityCredential
...

If your instance can't connect to the Azure key vault, it may not have the correct permissions for managed identity.

You need to enable managed identity on your App Service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp#add-a-system-assigned-identity

You need to assign permissions to access key vault for this managed identity:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad


